# Is the minimum number singular points of a continuous vector field on a 2-dimensional sphere 1 or 2?

Tags: topology, vector-fields, dipole

Let's look at a continuous vector field on a 2-dimensional sphere. Say the vector field representing the velocity of an infinitely thin layer of water on the sphere, or the direction of the Higgs field (which came into existence after the symmetry of the "Mexican hat" potential was broken; in 3-dimensional flat space the singular points in the continuous Higgs field give rise to things like 1d cosmic strings and 2d textures) at every point on the sphere.

I always thought that there had to be at least two singular points at which the field could not be defined. So if we make the well-known analogy with a tennis ball, all the hair (the vectors) can be continuously combed, but there will always be two points where continuity breaks down. If you comb the hair from the top down (which would imply the existence of sinks and sources in the case of the velocity vector field of water), two of those points emerge at the "north and south pole", and the same will happen if you comb all the hair sideways (by the way, it's clear that the rotation of the vector field isn't zero at every point on the sphere with except for the two singular points, where it's not defined).

But then I saw a picture of an electric dipole placed on a 2-dimensional sphere:

[image]

Is there really just one singular point (which would mean the two equal charges are on top of each other, producing no field at all), or are there two such points, very, very (though not infinitely, which would mean they coincide) close to each other on which the opposite charges are placed? In other words, is this just a mathematical construct which is out of touch with reality?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?